# Combine 2 tables and show all possible results for a given member

Tags: php, mysql

Assuming I have the following table structures

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `members`;

CREATE TABLE `members`
(
    m_id  INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  , m_upgrade TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0  COMMENT '0 - no upgrade, 1 - possible upgrade'
) ENGINE MyISAM
;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `upgrade_reasons`;

CREATE TABLE `upgrade_reasons`
(
    ur_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  , ur_by INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'Who upgraded me'
  , ur_for INT NOT NULL COMMENT 'who this upgrade is for'
  , ur_vote TINYINT DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'NULL - not yet voted, 0 - do not upgrade, 1 - upgrade'
  , ur_reason VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The reason for marking as upgrade / do not upgrade'
  , UNIQUE INDEX ur_idx(ur_by, ur_for)
) ENGINE MyISAM
;


INSERT INTO `members`(m_id, m_upgrade)
VALUES
    (1, 0)
  , (2, 0)
  , (3, 0)
  , (4, 1)
  , (5, 1)
;

INSERT INTO `upgrade_reasons`(ur_by, ur_for, ur_vote, ur_reason)
VALUES
    (2, 4, 1, 'Vote for')
  , (3, 4, 0, 'vote against')
  , (3, 5, 0, 'vote against')
;
```

for member 1, I would like to see the following results

```
+-----+-----------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+
|m_id | m_upgrade | ur_by | ur_for | ur_vote | ur_reason   |
+-----+-----------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+
|  4  |     1     | NULL  |   4    | NULL    | NULL        |
+-----+-----------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+
|  5  |     1     | NULL  |   5    | NULL    | NULL        |
+-----+-----------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+
```

for member 2, I would like to see the following results

```
+-----+-----------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+
|m_id | m_upgrade | ur_by | ur_for | ur_vote | ur_reason   |
+-----+-----------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+
|  4  |     1     |   2   |   4    | 1       | Vote for    |
+-----+-----------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+
|  5  |     1     | NULL  |   5    | NULL    | NULL        |
+-----+-----------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+
```

for member 3, I would like to see the following results

```
+-----+-----------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+
|m_id | m_upgrade | ur_by | ur_for | ur_vote | ur_reason   |
+-----+-----------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+
|  4  |     1     |   3   |   4    | 0       | vote against|
+-----+-----------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+
|  5  |     1     |   3   |   5    | 0       | vote against|
+-----+-----------+-------+--------+---------+-------------+
```

So far, I have tried nothing (other than searching StackOverflow) as I don't have a clue where to start.

NB. This is fora website coded in PHP, so if there is no purely SQL solution, I can do it in PHP

Thanks in advance

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: Updated question to metion searching this site

Comment: do you have any kind of experience in sql?

Comment: A small amount - usin basic SELECTs, LEFT JOINs, WHERE, GROUP BY, ORDER BY, LIMIT. I don't really understand HAVING :(

Comment: +1 for supplying `create` and `insert` statements.

Comment: @JR You can think of [`having`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_%28SQL%29) more or less as a `where` clause for the group by result.

Comment: @Olaf Dietsche - Thanks for the update re 'HAVING'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use [`joins`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) for this

```
select m1.m_id, m1.m_upgrade,
       ur.ur_by, coalesce(ur.ur_for, m1.m_id) as ur_for, ur.ur_vote, ur.ur_reason
from members m1
join members m2 on m2.m_id <> m1.m_id
left join upgrade_reasons ur on ur.ur_by = m2.m_id and ur.ur_for = m1.m_id
where m1.m_upgrade = 1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66c3a/37/0) for testing.

Comment: Wow - Magic. I think that will do the trick. I was missing the member table self-join (m1 and m2 in your example). Many thanks

Comment: By removing the COALESCE(..) function and adding m1.m_id as m1id, m2.m_id as m2id, I could see why I got 8 results when I thought there would be only 6. Many thanks - I never would have thought of the self-join.